# Simple React/Enzyme test failing over map issue

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a simple react component with a simple test. It is failing for some reason. Can someone take a look at this?

Here is the component.

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ToDoItem from '../ToDoItem/ToDoItem';

export default class ToDos extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const toDoItems = this.props.items.map((item, key) => (
            <ToDoItem item={item} key={key} />
        )); 

        return (
            <section> 
                { toDoItems }   
            </section>
        )
    }
}
```

Not rocket science. Here is the test:

```
it('displays all ToDo items passed as props', () => {
    const items = ['example1', 'example2']; 
    const toDos = mount(<ToDos items={items} />);
    expect(toDos.contains(<ToDoItem />)).toEqual(true);   
});
```

The test seems very bothered by "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" It can't seem to read the items props. Am I not passing the array properly in the test? I can't see what's wrong here. The code itself works fine. It's just the test... Help!

Comment: Nothing jumps out as incorrect...have you tried `console.log(this.props)` in `render`?

Comment: I tried this and got "HERE ARE THE PROPS { items: [ 'example1', 'example2'] }"

Comment: Which, again, seems strange, because they are clearly coming through...

Comment: Agreed. Not to sound super obvious, but are you certain that error message is coming from this test and isn't a Red Herring? I'm not sure the use of "contains" is correct there. From the Enzyme docs ".contains Returns whether or not a given node or array of nodes is somewhere in the render tree.".... and ".containsMatchingElement Returns whether or not a given react element is somewhere in the render tree.". Have yyou tried "containsMatchingElement"?

Answer (score 0):

you're not declaring any props in your component

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
}
```

Comment: Actually the code itself works fine. It's only the test that breaks. Tried that out and it wasn't the issue. Thanks though